# Concurrent updates in Spring Service with isolation=REPEATABLE_READ

Tags: java, spring

I have a Service method executing inside a transaction and updating a few tables. At the default isolation level, concurrent updates were overwriting each other. I don't want that to happen, so I am considering switching to REPEATABLE_READ. In doing so, I understand that I will get an Exception thrown from the DB driver when possible (using PostgreSQL so that is what will happen).

What is the most Spring-ish way to handle this? I was a little surprised that there doesn't seem to be anything built-in, but maybe I'm looking at the problem incorrectly.

In my case, I am trying to find the first "available" row to update. I want to avoid two concurrent transactions from updating the same row, but I want both to eventually update a row. The inelegant plan was to have a try/catch around the Service method and retry X times until the update completes (either finding a row to update or determining that there are no rows left to update). This feels pretty manual/heavy handed.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use isolation level serialized transactions. Thread A may throw an exception when thread B modifies the same record after thread A started the transaction and commits before thread A commits. I don't know Spring so I don't know whether you have to write a retry mechanism yourself or whether Spring does this for you.

Another solution is using the default isolation level (read committed). Add a 'modification_count' column to the table. When you read a record, you remember the modification count of the record. When you update the record, ensure to increase the modification count and only update if the modification count has the same value as when you read the record. So when you read a record with modification_count=15 then make sure the update looks like:

`update TABLE_NAME set value=1234, modification_count=16 where id=1234567 and modification_count=15`

Check the number of rows updated. If one row is updated everything went fine. If zero rows are udpated then another thread has updated the record in the meantime. In this case you have to retry your transaction.